# Inconsistent results with PHP Reflection API

Tags: php, reflection, line-endings

I have an application that works perfectly on both Windows & Mac that uses the PHP5 Reflection API.

I attempted to deploy the application to a Linux machine (CentOS box running PHP 5.3.6  -production server), only to find that the `ReflectionMethod::getDocComment()` function does not return anything. I investigated for a little while, and discovered that the line-endings were a potential culprit.

I used the `dos2unix` utility on my server to change the line-endings all to Unix-style, and the script works. Now here's the strange part: **it only works *once***. By this, I mean that the script which returns the data from `ReflectionMethod::getDocComment()` works once, and then (without any modification to the files on disk or the code) it reverts back to not working.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the script?

Comment: There's nothing strange or interesting about the script. It works perfectly on two machines using similar environments: it's definitely a line-endings issue which `ReflectionMethod::getDocComment()` may not be taking into consideration.

In any case, here is the script:
https://github.com/dannykopping/PHPDocBlock-lite/blob/master/lib/DocBlockParser.php#L167

It's part of an open-source project which parses doc-block comments :)

Comment: For what it's worth, a friend recommended I look into the caching elements of the server; turns out that eAccelerator was enabled. I disabled it, rebooted the server and now everything works! Could this issue have been cache-related? In which case, what is the best way to solve this problem besides disabling eAccelerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of turning it out globally you may use `php_flag` in your .htaccess like so :

```
php_flag eaccelerator.enable 0
php_flag eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

I had the same issue and it took me some time to figuring out (3 hours) because I didn't own the production server.