# Doctrine 2 / PHP - getDocComment() always returns false - AnnotationReader / DocParser fails

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I have quite an interesting (and annoying) problem here. For some reason, the PHP method [ReflectionClass::getDocComment()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php) is returning false on my production environment (while there actually is a block comment in the class of course...).

Causing the Doctrine AnnotationReader / DocParser to fail:

(Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader.php:143)

```
public function getClassAnnotations(ReflectionClass $class)
    {
        $this->parser->setTarget(Target::TARGET_CLASS);
        $this->parser->setImports($this->getImports($class));
        $this->parser->setIgnoredAnnotationNames($this->getIgnoredAnnotationNames($class));

        return $this->parser->parse($class->getDocComment(), 'class ' . $class->getName());
    }
```

I've looked around and haven't seen very much about this problem, so I'm wondering why this is happening on my Production server when it does not on my Local environment.

- Would it be because of some PHP config??
- Would it be because of some read / write / file access rights (chown, etc...)??
- Would it be because of some [caching configuration](https://eaccelerator.net/ticket/229)??

I must say I am running out of ideas.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Further investigations lead me to think that it is related to eAccelerator:

http://wildlyinaccurate.com/eaccelerator-and-doctrine-2/ &&

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676328/inconsistent-results-with-php-reflection-api

I'll try to disable it and find out if this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. This appeared to be linked to some strange behavior of eAccelerator stripping all the comments when caching the byte code...

http://wildlyinaccurate.com/eaccelerator-and-doctrine-2/

(Re-)Quoting beberlei from the Doctrine team:

> This premature optimization to remove the docblocks should be
>   reverted. Docblocks are a PHP Token for a reason, they are part of the
>   language and should be used that way. Please revise your stand on this
>   otherwise projects must suggest NOT to use eAccelerator by default.

Solution is either to disable eAccelerator OR to reconfigure it with the option:

```
--with-eaccelerator-doc-comment-inclusion
```

(Source: https://eaccelerator.net/ticket/229)